# FInd the height of a mergesort-tree

Tags: java, recursion, mergesort

I have an implementation of the mergesort algorithm. How do I calculate the height of the tree?

So far I can get the number of recursive calls, but not the height of the tree:

```
static int swaps=0;
static long comparisons=0;
static int recursionsdepth=0;

public static int[] sort(int[] array) {

    recursionsdepth++;
    if (array.length > 1) {

        int middle = (int)(array.length / 2);

        int[] left = new int[middle];
        for (int i = 0; i <= left.length - 1; i++) {
            left[i] = array[i];
        }

        int[] right = new int[array.length - middle];
        for (int i = middle; i <= array.length - 1; i++) {
            right[i - middle] = array[i];
        }

        left = sort(left);
        right = sort(right);

        return merge(left, right);
    }
    else
    {  
        recursionsdepth--;
        return array;
    }
}
```

For `{1,5,7,9}` the recursive calls are  3 ( 1 for `{1,5,7,9}` ,1 for `{1,5}` and 1 for `{7,9}`), but the height of the tree is 2.

Comment: Sounds like you should do some debugging.

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge Sort repeatedly divides the array into two equal (almost) parts as long as the array size is greater than 1. It doesn't care about the initial state of the array, i.e. it would do so even if the array is already sorted.
Now, there is only one way to do so for any given array of length n. And therefore, the height of the merge-sort tree will be constant with respect to n. That is the height will be **ceil(log n)** where base is 2. You don't need to actually run your program to find this out.

Since the OP is hell-bent on calculating the height while actually running the sorting code, here it is:

Pass an additional variable to the sort function that would store the depth of the current node. And use a global variable to store the maximum depth that has been achieved until now. Below code is slight modification of the one posted in the question:

```
static int swaps=0;
static long comparisons=0;
static int recursionsdepth=0;

public static int[] sort(int[] array, int depth) { // at first call depth = 0

    recursiondepth = Math.max(recursiondepth, depth);
    if (array.length > 1) {

        int middle = (int)(array.length / 2);

        int[] left = new int[middle];
        for (int i = 0; i <= left.length - 1; i++) {
            left[i] = array[i];
        }

        int[] right = new int[array.length - middle];
        for (int i = middle; i <= array.length - 1; i++) {
            right[i - middle] = array[i];
        }

        left = sort(left, depth+1);
        right = sort(right, depth+1);

        return merge(left, right);
    }
    else
    {  
        return array;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know how to calculate it mathematically...but I don't know how to calculate it using the given code.

Comment: Math.ceil(Math.log(n) / Math.log(2));
This should do.

Comment: As I mentioned above , I know how to calculate it ,but  my problem is how to include it in the code without doing math .

Comment: for input {1,2,3,4}  I get 1 ,shouldn't it be 2 ?

Comment: Oh. I had copied your code. Didn't see there was recursiondepth-- at the bottom of the code. That shouldn't be there. Updated the answer and removed it. It would give correct answer now.

Comment: Yes ,it is working now ! I also tried with Math.max(recursiondepth, depth+1) and it also worked!